# MySql "table doesnt exist"

Tags: mysql, xampp

I start with what I think is the beginning of my problem:

I exported a mysql database from a online server to a local server so I could test on it without risk.

But in XAMPP I couldn't restart the MySql Module. The

```
11:02:54  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
```

did nothing but throwing this error

```
10:57:49  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:57:49  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:57:49  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:57:49  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:57:49  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:57:49  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:57:49  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I looked it up on the internet and the only working solution I found, was to delete
the mysql/data/ibdata1 file before each startup. I knew its a dirty solution but it worked and I didn't want to waste much time on it.

Now the actual problem: I added a new table. After the next restart (including the delete of the ibdata1 file) I see the table on the left column in phpMyAdmin but when I click on the "+" its completly empty. When I click on the name I get the error

```
#1146 table doesnt exist
```

If I try to creat a new table with the same name, I get the same error.

This is the xampp logfile:

```
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-27 11:17:21 21e8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2013-09-27 11:17:21 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 0
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 9dce5432-2755-11e3-835a-20689d9d84a8.
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-09-27 11:17:22 4284 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-27 11:34:15 12d0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2203529 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-27 11:34:15 3928 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mydatabase/blackboard which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\tum_mitfahrer_app\blackboard.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\tum_mitfahrer_app\blackboard.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

its running on windows 8. could be something about missing permissions, but I reinstalled xampp from c:\program files\xampp to c:\xampp -> same problem. I have to delete ibdata1 to get it started, and every new table I create is gone after that.

Comment: How did you export/import the database?

Comment: In phpmyAdmin (Server Version: 5.5.29) I just clicked on export (as sql) and then imported the file in the phpmyAdmin instance of my local xampp (Server Version: 5.6.11)

Comment: And have you tried what it said? "_Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues_". You'll probably get more information which you can post here to find out exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a [known bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67595) in MySQL 5.6.
They also mention a workaround:

> [27 Nov 2012 8:39] Sunny Bains
>   This is a duplicate of bug#67179. Just different side effect. The Windows installer ? apparently copied the .ibd files around and that caused the problem. The ones in data/mysql. If you want to recover your files you will have to do the following:
>
> 1. Delete the data/mysql/*.ibd files and the corresponding .frm files for the .ibd files
> 2. Start the server with --skip-slave-start
> 3. You should be able to access and backup your data
>
> What I noticed was that on shutdown, you will get another failure. I need to investigate the cause of this other issue. I will post an update on this later.

If it doesn't work try [Restoring MySQL InnoDB Files on Windows](http://www.nerdydork.com/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows.html) which is slightly more XAMPP related.

Comment: When I create new tables in a format other than InnoDB (MyISAM e.g.) the table is still there after my "delete-ibdata1-before-restart" routine. For now that's all I need.